# Fresh ELK Install on Ubuntu 14.04, Kibana returns Connection Refused

Tags: ubuntu, kibana-4, elastic-stack

New Server running Ubuntu 14.04 server. Fresh install of ELK stack today. Check Elastic Search from Spyder on home Ubuntu machine. Result (using Python's Requests package):

```
res = requests.get('http://' + falcon618 + ':' + port)

print(res.content)
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Six of Nine",
  "cluster_name" : "{my cluster name}",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.4",
    "build_hash" : "c88f77ffc81301dfa9dfd81ca2232f09588bd512",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-02-19T13:05:36Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.3"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

However, when I go to `server_ip:5601` via Chrome I get a connection refused. When I ask Ubuntu for Kibana's status it says running. When I look at netstat -lnp there is an entry (listening) for port 9200 (elaticsearch) but no entry for port 5601.

I have searched and searched Google but can't find where the Kibana error log is. Nothing in ElasticSearch's logs would suggest an issue and obviously my home machine can see ES via the server's IP. I'm attempting to run Kibana from the same server. So in Kibana's config:

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This controls which port to use.
port: 5601

# The host to bind the server to.
host: "{server IP}"

# The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch_url: "http://{server IP}:9200"
```

First, where is the Kibana log? Second, any ideas on why this is happening? I've read several threads on people having a similar error message but none of them quite match.

I followed this page for installing ELK:
[ELK on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04)

However, I skipped the Nginx install and made ES available on the public IP. (Using iptables to reject everything not from a known server. But iptables is currently empty.)

--------- Edit to clarify Comments Below ----------

My first attempt at the ELK stack included Kibana on the same server that ElasticSearch was running on. However, since I wanted ElasticSearch to be available to my home servers I told it to listen to the server's public IP. So I've configured Kibana on that server to look for ElasticSearch on the server's IP.

I test ElasticSearch and have added approximately 3000 docs to it using my home server. I can retrieve those docs from the home server as well. So I set up Kibana on the home server to see if it would work. If Kibana worked on my LAN server that would suggest maybe a simple reinstall might fix the Kibana install on the WAN server. Or possibly some permissions or security issue.

The Kibana install on the WAN server has always returned `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome and still does. The Kibana install on the my LAN server shows Kibana but won't let me designate a default index pattern. The first page I come to asks for that pattern but there is no button to save the pattern. I have attempted to add the pattern via the Advanced Setting and it doesn't save.

Running `_cat/indices` on ElasticSearch returns the following:

```
yellow open visitors 5 1 3282 0 54.8mb 54.8mb 
yellow open .kibana  1 1    1 0  2.5kb  2.5kb
```

So there is clearly a `.kibana` index as well as my `visitors` index. The first time I ran this API call it took a while to display. However, since then these indices have come up very fast.

----- Edit #2 ------

I have now tried to install Kibana on another WAN server I lease. The results are identical to my LAN server. It loads but there is still no button to save it. When I enter in an index pattern and hit return the 3 white dots in the upper right cycle. After a long while I get the "No living connections" error.

It doesn't appear to be able to connect to ES but this really seems to be a timeout issue I think. From this WAN server #2 I can curl ES and get the proper response but it takes a long time - possibly even a full minute. When I use curl to get the indices I didn't time it but it seemed to take at least a couple of minutes.

On top of that I've been wondering about the visitors index. It has approximately 3000 entries that take 3K of disk space each so a total of approximately 9M. However, in the index they take up over 50M.

Finally, while everything with ES appears to be working it is also very slow. When I do a search I get the right answer but only after several seconds. My entire WordPress site can load faster (on WAN server #2) than I can get 3K worth of JSON text. (Both WAN server are identical specs - 8 core AMD, 32 GB RAM, Ubuntu 14.04 with 100 Mbps pipe.)

-------- Edit #3 --------

While I still have not found a solution to this I have another piece to he puzzle. DIgitalOcean offers an ELK stack ready to go so I got one. It worked just fine and I could see data in Kibana and it looked like local server log data. Great!

However, I then changed the ElasticSearch cluster name and restarted ES. Then Kibana looked to have the same issues as I describe above where I can't define a default index pattern.

So I rebooted the machine. Now I get a `502 Bad Gateway Error`. Then I changed ES back to the default cluster name - elasticsearch - and rebooted. Still a `502`.

Hmmmm. Here's hoping DigitalOcean's support can figure this out.

-------- Edit #4 ---------

After wasting way too much time on this I started up a DigitalOcean image of an ELK stack on Ubuntu 14.04. Even that broke as soon as I changed the cluster name in the elsaticsearch.yml config file.

However, with DO support's help I figured out that the cluster parameter needs to be added to the logstash config files as well. So to use DO's example of a cluster named snuggles:

/etc/logstash/conf.d/30-lumberjack-output.conf:

```
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost cluster => snuggles }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-lumberjack-input.conf:

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    cluster => "snuggles"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }

}
```

/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:

```
cluster.name: snuggles
```

This got it working on DO's image. I assume that image is based on this tutorial:
[ELK on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I still have not gotten this stack working on any other machine. The Marvel plugin is working on my original - non-DO - server and displaying some nice data about the cluster... of 1.

Comment: By default kibana logs to stdout, you can change that in the config file (look for the `log_file` property). Change that to log to a file instead and we'll get more insights.

Comment: My ~/kibana-4*/config/kibana.yml file did not have log_file param so I added it (and restarted the service) just to see if would take and it either did not use it or it didn't log any thing.

Comment: I have installed Kibana on a local machine and hooked it up to my ElasticSearch instance on my WAN server. In this case I can get Kibana to run and respond but it won't find any indices. I currently have 1 index - visitors - which has about 3000 docs in it. I run a query (from that machine in iPython via Spyder + elasticsearch.py). The query returned the doc I expected.

Comment: What do you see in "Settings > Indices"?

Comment: Index Patterns -> Warning - No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue. When I run /_cat/indices on the ES server it is slow to respond but comes back with 2 indices - visitors and .kibana. Visitors is returning queries properly and is listed at 54.8 MB so something is in there.

Comment: Type your index name in the input field labeled "Index name or pattern". Is the `visitors` index found?

Comment: Tried entering visitors index before creating the question. (And again very recently.) I never get a button to click to make it stick/save.